# Convert date type in c# to match sql server 2008 date type

Tags: c#, sql

I have retrieved a date from an application and stored it in a DateTime Variable. The format of date is dd/mm/yyyy.

I now want to update a column (with datatype date (yyyy/mm/dd)) in a sql server 2008 database with this date
I have tried the below code, but it's giving me an exception "string was not recognized as valid datetime". Please help to solve this problem.

```
DateTime date = calExpirydate.SelectedDate;
DateTime date1 = DateTime.ParseExact(date.ToString(), "YYYY/MM/DD", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Why are you converting the `datetime` to a string and then parsing it to create a new datetime?

Comment: If you pass the date as a parameter value, it will be  converted implicitly.

Comment: A `DateTime` value has no format in itself. Formating matters only when you convert to string for user visualization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to convert it at all if you use parameters (and you should be).

A rough example:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table (date) VALUES (@date)";   
command.Parameters.Add("@date",SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = date;
```

*I'm using SQL Server here, however the concept is similar across most ADO.NET providers.*

Comment: I don't see [a overload of `Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.Add(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes `String, object, SqlDbType`. I think you want `Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = date`

Answer (score 0):

Your DateTime variable in the framework is stored in one basic format.  The way it appears is just formatting off of the .ToString.  It's saying give me your date bit make it look like this.  Sql server is similar, it understands the date time variable regardless of how it appears.

If you pass your DateTime as exactly how it is in the framework it will save it correctly.  The date and time isn't changing just how it's displayed.  Your try parse isn't working though because it's not able to recognize the partial string you're giving it.

You don't even need a new date time variable to see it the way you want.   Even if you're successful you will have identical date time variables.

Answer (score -1):

yyyy/MM/dd should be correct

[DateTime string format](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

Comment: No, its not, it all depends on what `date.ToString()` outputs for his current culture. However he should not be converting the date to a string at all to accomplish what he wants! just pass the DateTime to the SQL query via parameters.

Comment: The only string format that SQL Server recognizes unequivocally is `yyyyMMdd` (without slashes), all others have some chance of being misinterpreted depending on the server settings (switching days and months is a typical bug), so that's the only you should use in the rare event that interpolating parameter data is the best option. In 99% of the cases using parametrized queries is the way to go, which also removes the formating problem.